# My search results open in samsung browers rather than chrome browers

Tags: browser

How can I change it to chrome rather than Samsung on my samsung s3 tablet?
 I do not know how to change it

Comment: Please do a search for "android change default browser"

Answer (score 0):

Go inside your Samsung S3 tablet settings. After that select Apps. When you select apps you will see every installed app in your tablet. Now press the three dots on the upper right corner and select Default Apps option. The next page will show you a variety of options including Browser App and in there you can select chrome.

Alternatively as soon as you enter settings do a search for Default Apps and it will take you directly to the default apps page.